# How to mount a WSL2 folder as a Network Drive in Windows 10+?

Tags: windows-10, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, network-drive

I have created a shared folder in my WSL2 instance (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS) which seems to be accessible and working. I created the folder in the `/mnt/wsl` location. After that, I can access the new folder in *Windows File Explorer* using `\\wsl$\`.

[image: preview1]

Everything seems to be perfect. However, my main challenge is that I must access the folder *ae-games* from a .NET App. We are trying to mount it as a *Network Drive*, but when we try it says the path doesn't exist:

[image: preview2]

[image: preview3]

We are trying to mount the drive because the folder contains thousands of files that we are analyzing coming from an *[EFS Shared Drive](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)* in AWS.

Our current workaround is copying the files from EFS to Windows every couple of hours. However, this is problematic because the shared drive is massive, and S3 is not an option because of [ECS and Fargate limitations](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/412).

Does anyone know if this is a WSL2 limitation that we can't mount as a Network Drive? Or can someone guide me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It was good to see that you (or someone else on your team) posted this as a feature request for the WSL team ([#8765 for anyone else interested](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8765)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that for now, the only way to do it is mounting the "Root" folder: `\\wsl$\Ubuntu`:

[image: preview 1]

[image: preview 2]

Now, I can access it as `Z:\mnt\wsl\efs\ae-games`

It's important to highlight that this will fail if you want to mount only one specific folder. Most likely, it was designed like this from the very beginning.

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3854#issuecomment-631356968

**Note:**

I wrote this [tutorial](https://supernovaic.blogspot.com/2022/08/how-to-access-efs-folders-from-file.html) with all the steps if it's useful for anyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use subst command to do that: `subst z: \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\user` .