# Windows WSL2 network drive authentication issue

Tags: windows-10, wsl2

I am using

```
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2022.3"
VERSION_ID="2022.3"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```

on `5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2` on [Windows 10 22H2 Insider Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKn9z.jpg) to [map a network drive to a subfolder 'aka non-root folder'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlmAi.jpg) that required credentials I couldn't find in both Windows and WSL, be it [root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe6kg.jpg), [my main Linux user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTdOL.jpg), or even [my Windows user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZ7DD.jpg). The problem persists with all subdirs while the root can be mounted directly through Windows Explorer.
What I need is a valid credential to map the WSL network share 'aka `\\wsl.localhost\<distro-name>\<directory>`', or a method to remove the login requirement whenever I map such path as a network drive

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: WSL isn’t _really_ a network share and as such may not offer all features.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, it is _not_ a network share, but it _does_ offer network share for native Windows applications. You can try for yourself or search Microsoft Docs for further information. As far as I know, _all_ WSL distro support this, be it version 1 or 2, Kali or Ubuntu,... And once mapped to network drives, all accessible files **depending on default UNIX user** can be operated as a native file _without ACLs of course_

Comment: It really does not. Yes, it is a UNC path. Yes, it is _mostly_ transparent. However, there’s an almost entirely different software stack (p9np) underneath. If it doesn’t support mapping subfolders to drive letters, that’s it. Unfortunately, mapping network drives uses different functionality from, say, opening a UNC path in Notepad.

Comment: @DanielB It sounds to me like you and Nguyễn are saying the same thing for the most part.  Yes, 9P is a network filesystem, but it doesn't (at least the WSL implementation) support mapping to a subfolder, just the top-level folder, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds No, it does, else such login box wouldn't appear. What I need is the **credentials** for access.

Comment: @DanielB And I also noticed a weird thing... When [another person](https://superuser.com/users/1723568/federico-navarrete) [attempted the same procedure](https://superuser.com/questions/1738361/how-to-mount-a-wsl2-folder-as-a-network-drive-in-windows-10?rq=1), it just returned an error, which mean that somehow _some_ machines does **not** support this, which was **very diffrent** from mine, where it _asked for credentials_ instead. So I guess your concern was that _none_ WSL install actually do that, and that mine was rather _special_, which means we may have to investigate this in detail.

Comment: @NguyễnTrọngCường Could just be a bug (or simply unimplemented error trap) in the older WSL version or in Windows 10 Insider.  Under Windows 11 22H2, it does not offer the credentials dialog (unless I specifically tick that checkbox).  It correctly returns an error dialog with `Network Error` - `0x80070043 The network name cannot be found` for me.